# C# switch namespaces using an array

Tags: c#, namespaces

Good day!I'm wondering if it is possible to write a namespace switch at compile time?

I was thinking about creating some object (containing my namespaces) or an array of these spaces, so that later I would not do all the time checking for the used namespace.

Or maybe try to use an alias instead of an object? To find out once which library we are using and assign it to an alias?

For example, I have two namespaces lib1 and lib2, they store different data, but with the same class name. I would like to make a handler in the main method, for example: if the software is working in a regular mode, then we will use classes from the lib1 library, if the debugging mode (training methods, not a real debugger), then from lib2.

Comment: Namespaces are a compile time concept, so no, you wouldn't be switching them whilst running.

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks for the answer. What if you then do this at compile time?

Comment: You can use conditional compilation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation.

Comment: Evk,thanks,it's work!